# $f(x + iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ holomorphic implies that $F(x,y) = (u(x,y), v(x,y))$ is differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-riemann-equations

My question comes from section 1.6 of *Complex Analysis* (4th edition) by Serge Lang:

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and let
\begin{align*}
    f(x + iy) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y), \qquad x + iy \in U
\end{align*}

be a complex-valued function on $U$. Lang argues that if $f$ is holomorphic at some point $z = x + iy$, then the real vector field associated with $f$ is differentiable at $(x,y)$. However, I don't quite follow the argument. The relevant passage is below:

> At a fixed $z$, let $f'(z) = a + ib$. Let $w = h + ik$, with $h,k$ real. Suppose that
> $$
>      f(z + w) - f(z) = f'(z) w + \sigma(w) w,
> $$
>
> where
> $$
>      \lim_{w \to 0} \sigma(w) = 0.
> $$
>
> Then
> $$
>       f'(z) w = (a + ib)(h + ik) = ah - bk + i(ak + bh).
> $$
>
> On the other hand, let
> $$
>      F: U \to \mathbb{R}^2
> $$
> be the map such that
> $$
>      F(x,y) = \big( u(x,y), v(x,y) \big).
> $$
>
> We call $F$ the (real) **vector field associated with** $f$. Then
> $$
>     F(x + h, y + k) - F(x,y) = (ah - bk, bh + ak) + \sigma_1(h,k) h + \sigma_2(h,k) k, \hspace{1cm} (1)
> $$
>
> where $\sigma_1(h,k), \, \sigma_2(h,k)$ are functions tending to $0$ as $(h,k)$ tends to $0$. Hence if we assume that $f$ is holomorphic, we conclude that $F$ is differentiable in the sense of real variables, and that its derivative is represented by the (Jacobian) matrix
> $$
>     J_F(x,y) = 
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>           a & -b \\
>           b & \phantom{-} a
>     \end{pmatrix}
>     = 
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>         \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\[10pt]
>         \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}
>     \end{pmatrix}. 
> $$

**My questions:** How was equation (1) obtained? Moreover, if it appears that $\sigma = \sigma_1 + i \sigma_2$, in which case $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are real-valued functions. But then in the right-hand side of (1) we are adding the scalar quantity $\sigma_1(h,k) k + \sigma_2(h,k) k$ to the vector $(ah - bk,bh + ak)$...how does that make sense?

Here is my attempt at deducing the differentiability of $F$: We have
\begin{align*}
    F(x,y) &= \Big( \text{Re}\big(f(x + iy) \big), \text{Im} \big(f(x + iy) \big) \Big) \\[5pt]
           &= \big( \text{Re}\big(f(z) \big), \text{Im} \big(f(z) \big) \big)  
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
    F(x + h, y + k) &= \Big( \text{Re}\big(f(x + h + i(y+k)) \big), \text{Im} \big(f(x + h + i(y+k)) \big) \Big)  \\[5pt]
    &= \Big( \text{Re} \big(f(z + w) \big), \text{Im}\big(f(z+w) \big) \Big)
\end{align*}

Now using the fact that $\text{Re}(z_1 + z_2) = \text{Re}(z_1) + \text{Re}(z_2)$ and $\text{Im}(z_1 + z_2) = \text{Im}(z_1) + \text{Im}(z_2)$, it follows that

\begin{align*}
    F(x + h, y + k) - F(x,y) &=  \big( \text{Re} \big(f(z + w) \big), \text{Im}\big(f(z+w) \big) \big) - \big( \text{Re}\big(f(z) \big), \text{Im} \big(f(z) \big) \big)  \\[5pt]
    &= \big( \text{Re} \big( f(z + w) - f(z) \big), \text{Im} \big( f(z + w) - f(z) \big) \big). 
\end{align*}

Now writing $\sigma(w) = \sigma(h + ik) = \sigma_1(h,k) + i \sigma_2(h,k)$, we have
\begin{align*}
    f(z + w) - f(z) &= f'(z) w + \sigma(w) w \\[3pt]
    &= (a + ib)(h + ik) + \big[\sigma_1(h,k) + i \sigma_2(h,k) \big] (h + ik) \\[3pt]
    &= (ah - bk) + i(ak + bh) + h \sigma_1(h,k) - k \sigma_2(h,k) + i \left[k \sigma_1(h,k) + h \sigma_2(h,k) \right]  \\[3pt]
    &= \big[ ah - bk + h \sigma_1(h,k) - k \sigma_2(h,k) \big] + i \big[ak + bh + k \sigma_1(h,k) + h \sigma_2(h,k)  \big]. 
\end{align*}

Hence, I get
\begin{align*}
  & F(x + h, y + k) - F(x,y)  \\[3pt]
 = \; &\big( ah - bk + h \sigma_1(h,k) - k \sigma_2(h,k), ak + bh + k \sigma_1(h,k) + h \sigma_2(h,k) \big) \\[5pt]
    = \; & \big(ah - bk, ak + bh \big) + \big( h \sigma_1(h,k) - k \sigma_2(h,k), k \sigma_1(h,k) + h \sigma_2(h,k) \big), 
\end{align*}

which is different than what the book has...So does the book have a mistake, or did I make a mistake in my calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ are not the functions as you defined them in your proof. Let us write
$$\sigma(w) = \sigma(h,k) = \bar \sigma_1(h,k) + i \bar \sigma_2(h,k)$$
with real-valued functions $\bar \sigma_1, \bar \sigma_2$. Then we get
\begin{align*}
  & F(x + h, y + k) - F(x,y)  \\[3pt]
   = \; & \big(ah - bk, ak + bh \big) + \big( h \bar \sigma_1(h,k) - k \bar \sigma_2(h,k), k \bar \sigma_1(h,k) + h \bar \sigma_2(h,k) \big) \\
= \; & \big(ah - bk, ak + bh \big) + \big(\bar \sigma_1(h,k),\bar \sigma_2(h,k)\big)h  + \big(-\bar \sigma_2(h,k), \bar \sigma_1(h,k)\big)k . 
\end{align*}

Now take $\sigma_1(h,k) = \big(\bar \sigma_1(h,k),\bar \sigma_2(h,k)$ and $\sigma_2(h,k) = \big(-\bar \sigma_2(h,k), \bar \sigma_1(h,k)\big)$.

These are functions with values in $\mathbb R^2$ tending to $0$ as $(h,k)$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would've been nice if the book had properly defined $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$...